# How to use keyup in ckeditor

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ckeditor

I am using angular js for development.

Initializing ck editor on controller

```
function initEditor(){
    CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
        on: {
            pluginsLoaded: function( evt )
            {
                var doc = CKEDITOR.document, ed = evt.editor;
                if ( !ed.getCommand( 'bold' ) )
                    doc.getById( 'exec-bold' ).hide();
                if ( !ed.getCommand( 'link' ) )
                    doc.getById( 'exec-link' ).hide();
            }
        }
    });

}
```

Html

```
<textarea cols="100" id="editor1" name="editor1" rows="50"></textarea>
```

I have tried several way to find key up but not working

```
CKEDITOR.instances["editor1"].on('keyup', function() {
    alert('key up');
}
```

I have refereed some other SO answers also , nothing seems to be working . Is it because of i am using angular js controller .

Please suggest a way to do this

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.instances["editor1"] ;
    editor.on( 'contentDom', function() {
        var editable = editor.editable();

        editable.attachListener( editor.document, 'keydown', function() {
            console.log('key up');
        } );
    } );
```

Comment: Extra: Callback function passes event object full of useful data.